Why is OneDrive creating "Camera Roll 1" folder?
I have {onedrive}\Pictures\Camera Roll folder which contains photos synced from my iPhone via the OneDrive app.
But quite often, new photos are synced into a new folder named {onedrive}\Pictures\Camera Roll 1. If I delete this folder, it just returns after the next OneDrive sync operation.
How can I stop OneDrive creating this numbered folder and just use the normal one?

It sounds like OneDrive does not have access to Camera Roll so it's creating a folder that it does have access too, per Windows rules when create a new folder the same as a folder that already exists a number is used to resolve the conflict.

@ramhound Thanks for the tip. It does look like there is some sort of read only flag on the Camera Roll folder or some of it's contents.I've now removed the flag, will wait and see if the Camera Roll 1 folder returns...

try go to OneDrive settings>account>choose folders and remove the checkbox by Documents, also uninstall oneddrive, delete both folders and all of their files, then wait hours then install again. a high level of confidence this solution would work.

